# Disabling Caps Lock doesn't work: still results in 0x2 state (running in VMware)

Tags: keyboard, vmware, xkb, xev

I am running an Ubuntu 21.10 guest in VMware, with a Windows 11 host.

I would like to disable all Caps Lock functionality, and use the key as Meta_R.
I've tried disabling it with `xmodmap -e "clear Lock"`, and `setxkbmap -option caps:none`.

But when I press Caps Lock, the light on my keyboard turns on, and when I type, the key presses result in upper case characters being printed.

This may be caused by VMware? VMware changes keyboard state depending on which window is active on the host, and may set the Caps Lock state via the kernel or similar.

I was thinking that a solution might be to disable the effect the 0x2 state has on the keyboard's symbol map?

**Result: xmodmap correctly shows Caps Lock as disabled...**

```
$ xmodmap
xmodmap:  up to 4 keys per modifier, (keycodes in parentheses):

shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock      
control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_R (0x69)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Alt_R (0x6c),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3      
mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)
```

**Result: xev shows state as 0x2**

Pressing the 'a' key results in 'a'.

```
KeyPress event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x1400001,
    root 0x1b8, subw 0x0, time 678615, (118,123), root:(368,501),
    state 0x0, keycode 38 (keysym 0x61, a), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (61) "a"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (61) "a"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Pressing Caps Lock correctly results in 'VoidSymbol'

```
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x1400001,
    root 0x1b8, subw 0x0, time 680515, (118,123), root:(368,501),
    state 0x0, keycode 66 (keysym 0xffffff, VoidSymbol), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Releasing Caps Lock incorrectly changes state to 0x2.

```
KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x1400001,
    root 0x1b8, subw 0x0, time 680655, (118,123), root:(368,501),
    state 0x2, keycode 66 (keysym 0xffffff, VoidSymbol), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Pressing 'a' with state 0x2 results in the symbol 'A'.

```
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x1400001,
    root 0x1b8, subw 0x0, time 682240, (118,123), root:(368,501),
    state 0x2, keycode 38 (keysym 0x41, A), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (41) "A"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (41) "A"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Comment: Hello. There is not such version of Ubuntu as 21

Comment: Is this 21.04 or 21.10?

Comment: You're right. This is Ubuntu 21.10.

Comment: what if you add one more xmodmap command; `xmodmap -e "keycode 66 ="`? presumably, 66 is the keycode for caps lock.

Comment: Yes I tried that as well. I can remap the keycode, e.g. to `Hyper_R`, so it's detected correctly in `xev`, but for some reason, state still gets set to 0x2.